# Unable to invoke a DBContext constructor from repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, dbcontext

I am looking to create a signalR Hub to get the SQL record updates in real time, using SQLDependency.
I used the EFCore Scaffolding database to create models as well as the DBContext, and using the repository pattern to work on retrieving data from the DB.

```
 private Func<DBAContext> _contextFactory;
    public Repository(Func<DBAContext> ContextFactory)
    {
        this._contextFactory = ContextFactory;
    }

    public someMethod()
    {
        using (var context = _contextFactory())
        {
            return context.Account.LastOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

Here's the issue:  on invoking context, I get "Constructor on Type DBContext not found.

DBAContext.cs

```
public partial class DBAContext : DbContext
{
    public DBAContext(DbContextOptions<DBAContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Account> Account { get; set; }
}
.
.
.//OnConfiguring
.//Autogenerated onModelCreating
```

Here is where the error occurs:

```
  public static void AddDbContextFactory<TDataContext>(this IServiceCollection services, string 
  connectionString) where TDataContext : DbContext
  {
            services.AddSingleton<Func<TDataContext>>((ctx) =>
            {
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder()
                .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
                .Options;

   
            return () => (TDataContext)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TDataContext), options);
        });
    }
}
```

Activator.CreateInstance is unable to resolve a constructor on the DBAContext class.

Startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContextFactory<DBAContext> 
(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
```

If anyone could explain me the issue, I'd really appreciate it
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You're doing what EF Core's DI extensions already do. `AddDbContext` does what this factory method is trying to do. Apart from that, putting a low-level "generic" repository on top of a high-level ORM is an *anti*pattern. A DbContext is already a Unit-of-Work, a DbSet is already a repositry

Comment: You can check the [source code of AddDbContext](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/b970bf29a46521f40862a01db9e276e6448d3cb0/src/EFCore/Extensions/EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L534) to see how it does the same thing you try to do.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for the explanation!! I probably need to spend more time on the fundamentals.